# Sending message via MassTransit in a transaction with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, masstransit, quartz.net

Background:
We are using [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) to schedule when a message should be sent to a RabbitMQ queue using [MassTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/). All messages are also saved to a database using Entity Framework, both for audit reasons as well as for recovery; rescheduling non-sent messages during application startup since Quartz are keeping the scheduled jobs (messages to be sent) in-memory. When a message is sent the database is updated, setting a flag on the message entity stating that is has been sent so it won't be re-sent during next application startup.

Problem:
The application can die after the database has been updated, before the message is sent, causing the message to never be sent. If we flip the order of operations and send the message first the application may crash before the database is updated, thus re-sending the message during next application startup. We would like to perform the two operations as a single transaction.

We have managed to use a transaction in a consumer, getting a `TransactionContext` from `ConsumeContext<T>.GetPayload<TransactionContext>()` and passing it to `DbContext.EnlistTransaction()`. Are there any similar options available using an `ISendEndpointProvider`?

Below is the (slimmed down) version of the Quartz IJob implementation. We have to create a scope for EF since Quartz is running as a singleton. What options do we have, if any, when it comes to solving the above problem?

We are using MassTransit 7.2.3, Quartz 3.3.3 and Entity Framework Core 5.0.11.

```cs
public sealed class ScheduleMessageJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ScheduleMessageJob(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) =>
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var scopedServiceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
        await UpdateScheduledMessage(scopedServiceProvider);
        await Send(scopedServiceProvider);
    }

    private static async Task UpdateScheduledMessage(IServiceProvider scopedServiceProvider)
    {
        var dbContext = scopedServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbContext>();
        var scheduledMessage = await dbContext.Get<ScheduledMessage>(id: 1);
        scheduledMessage.IsQueued = true;
        dbContext.Update(scheduledMessage);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public static async Task Send(IServiceProvider scopedServiceProvider)
    {
        var endpoint = await GetEndpoint(scopedServiceProvider);
        var triggerExecuted = new TriggerExecuted("Some data");
        await endpoint.Send(triggerExecuted);
    }

    private static async Task<ISendEndpoint> GetEndpoint(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) =>
        await serviceProvider
        .GetRequiredService<ISendEndpointProvider>()
        .GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:SomeQueue"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most message brokers are not transactional and do not participate in transactions. Expected distributed transaction consistency in the situation you described above is, well, a mistake. Or that least a really, really bad idea.

You can chose to rely on either the message broker (my preference) or the database. You can also write messages to the database *after* they've been consumed, either using the Audit capability (which observes all sent/published/consumed messages and writes them into a database) or via a separate consumer for that message type.

Quartz has a trigger re-fire capability, so you can retry failed triggers. I'd use a durable Quartz data store first, write to the broker second, and then deal with your database last.